# How to extract value from dict inside list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have below dict inside list, `dictlist` have `g1` to `g4` key and inside many key,pair. I want to print `a` and `23` with group title with sum of value for each group, desire output as below:

```
dictlist = { "g1" : [], "g2" : [] , "g3" : [] }

a = ["a", 23]
a1 = ["asd", 3]
a2 = ["asdf", 10]
a3 = ["adg", 5]

b1 = ["df", 5]
b2 = ["dfg", 1]

c = ["dfg", 50]

dictlist.["g1"].append[a]
dictlist.["g1"].append[a1]
dictlist.["g1"].append[a2]
dictlist.["g1"].append[a3]

dictlist.["g2"].append[b]
dictlist.["g2"].append[b1]

dictlist.["g3"].append[c]
```

I tried as below :

```
for i in dictlist.items():
  for k,v in i.item():
     print(k,v)
```

Desire output:

```
g1
a, 23
asd,3
asdf,10
adg,5
total, 41

g2
df,5
dfg,1
total, 6

 ...
```

Can anyone help for extract data with sum of each group ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** For adding the `total`, read till the end

Firstly, to get a value of a certain value in a dict, the indexing is as follows

`dict["key"]` and not `dict.["key"]`

Secondly, to append something to a list use parenthesis not square brackets. So,
`.append(x)` not `.append[x]`

Fixing these two things we have as of now:

```
dictlist = { "g1" : [], "g2" : [] , "g3" : [] }

a = ["a", 23]
a1 = ["asd", 3]
a2 = ["asdf", 10]
a3 = ["adg", 5]

b1 = ["df", 5]
b2 = ["dfg", 1]

c = ["dfg", 50]

dictlist["g1"].append(a)
dictlist["g1"].append(a1)
dictlist["g1"].append(a2)
dictlist["g1"].append(a3)

dictlist["g2"].append(b1)
dictlist["g2"].append(b2)

dictlist["g3"].append(c)
```

```
#Now, you want to print the key of the dict as the heading, so our first loop will be:
for heading in dict.keys(): # dictlist.keys() returns a list of all the keys
    print(heading)

#The next thing you want is to print the values of the respective key seperated by ",":
    for value in dict[heading]:
        print(*value, sep=",")  # we can use the sep keyword to print it as we require

# The at the end, an empty print() to seperate the headings
    print()
```

Output:

```
g1
a, 23
asd, 3
asdf, 10
adg, 5

g2
df, 5
dfg, 1

g3
dfg, 50
```

**Now, for adding the `total`:**

```
for heading in dict.keys():
    print(heading)

    total = 0  # We make a variable, becomes zero for every heading
    for value in dict[heading]: # value is a list like ["a", 23], has str and int.. So;
        total += sum(item for item in value if type(item) == int)
        print(*value, sep=",")

    #print the total before starting the next heading
    print("total," total)
    print()
```

Output:

```
g1
a, 23
asd, 3
asdf, 10
adg, 5
total,  41

g2
df, 5
dfg, 1
total,  6

g3
dfg, 50
total,  50
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a dict inside a list.  You have lists inside a dict.  Once you fix the spelling errors (`append` is a function and should use parens, not brackets, and you don't have `b` and `b1`, you have `b1` and `b2`), your code produces exactly the structure you describe.  It doesn't PRINT that way, because that's not how Python prints lists, but the data is all there:

```
dictlist = { "g1" : [], "g2" : [] , "g3" : [] }

a = ["a", 23]
a1 = ["asd", 3]
a2 = ["asdf", 10]
a3 = ["adg", 5]

b1 = ["df", 5]
b2 = ["dfg", 1]

c = ["dfg", 50]

dictlist["g1"].append(a)
dictlist["g1"].append(a1)
dictlist["g1"].append(a2)
dictlist["g1"].append(a3)

dictlist["g2"].append(b1)
dictlist["g2"].append(b2)

dictlist["g3"].append(c)
print(dictlist)

for k, v in dictlist.items():
   print(k)
   for i in v:
       print(i)
```

Output:

```
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ python x.py
{'g1': [['a', 23], ['asd', 3], ['asdf', 10], ['adg', 5]], 'g2': [['df', 5], ['dfg', 1]], 'g3': [['dfg', 50]]}
g1
['a', 23]
['asd', 3]
['asdf', 10]
['adg', 5]
g2
['df', 5]
['dfg', 1]
g3
['dfg', 50]
timr@tims-gram:~/src$
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is each item in `dictlist` a list if you want to treat it as a dictionary? I'd recommend dict in dict approach instead:

```
dictlist = { "g1" : {}, "g2" : {}, "g3" : {} }
a = ["a", 23] # does this really need to be a list?

# assign `a` value (23) into `a` key ("a")
dictlist['g1'][a[0]] = a[1]

# print all items from dictlist
for key, val in dictlist.items():
    print(key)
    for subkey, subval in val.items():
        print(subkey, ",", subval)
```

If you want to keep the list-in-dict instead, it would look like this

```
dictlist = { "g1" : {}, "g2" : {}, "g3" : {} }
a = ["a", 23] # does this really need to be a list?

# assign `a` value (23) into `a` key ("a")
dictlist['g1'].append(a)

# print all items from dictlist
for key, val in dictlist.items():
    print(key)
    for subkey, subval in val: # only difference: dont use `.items()`
        print(subkey, ",", subval)
```